# php and mysql query layout

Tags: php, mysql

im just learning php..

i have a little blog.. with categories and posts.

now i want to have a layout.. it have to be a list of all categories with 3 columns. number of all posts in the category, number of published and number of unpublished posts..

now i have 3 queries in 3 functions. (all, published, unpublished). it works fine if i call that functions sparely, but i dont know ho to connect in one forloop and also works if there is some of the number zero (it broke the list because of missing line)..

maybe im going wrong way.. i dont know if its possible but i was thing i can do better with them if i can call all 3 counts in one query.

this is what i got.. (one of the function - for published):

```
$query = "select count(i.id) as cislo, a.name"
        . " FROM item as i"
        . " JOIN application a ON a.id = i.application_id"
        . " where i.state = '0'"
        . " group by i.application_id";

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $riadky= $db->loadObjectList();
    ?>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($riadky as $riadok)
        {

            echo "<li> <span>"; echo($riadok->name);
            echo "</span> <span><strong>";
            echo($riadok->cislo);
            echo "</span></strong></li>";
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what exactly you want to do, but if you are trying to get all those posts in one query, then in MySQL you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM post;
```

Then in your PHP you can loop through each result and check if it is published or unpublished and put it in its proper column. As for number of posts in each category this can be handled by incrementing a counting variable as you loop through the results.

Comment: no.. i want to have a list.. category name- number of all posts, nubmer of published posts and number of unpublished.. this is the layout of my 3 functions.. http://i59.tinypic.com/2ypgmlw.png

Comment: yes, you loop through each result and build lists based on the result.

Comment: ok.. and how to get a result (empty <li> tag) even if there is 0?

Comment: Just check `if result == 0 then makeEmptyList()`